# Check for cookies from a domain different than the current site

Tags: javascript, php

I have a few cookies saved on my site that when I've visited an specific site.
how can I check those cookies with php or js?

```php
<?php 
if ( isset( $_COOKIE['fgvisitor'] ) ) {echo 'fgvisitor exists';} 
else { echo 'no fgvisitor'; }
?>
```

From the inspector I can see the cookie exists from a different domain that I've visited...
how can I have have that code check for the cookie?

[screenshot link](http://prnt.sc/p8i5bw)

[image]

Comment: you can't - that would be a security issue

Comment: from your sub domains its possible but if its coming from let's say facebook, no you can't

Comment: fgvisitor is coming from an external domain, they have provided a tracking pixel code. but I'm unable to write a function to check, I see it from my browser.

Comment: Basically, all I want is a way to create a cookie on my site, if the user has visited an specific site... is there a better way?

Comment: no, your site can not access such personal data - why would I want you to see what other sites I visit? They'd make you blush

Comment: They are a directory site, if the user see my site link but doesn't click and decides to manually type my site, or search. the directory loses the referral fee. so they add cookie track, so when the user access my site I see they have seen my link over the other site

Comment: The screenshot above is from my site btw, why would it save data from that other site directory on my sites' browser cookies, if it can't be used by my site?

Answer (score 1):

Checking cookie across domain violates browser security so you cannot do this freely. To make this sort of tracking work, you have to have control over the server programming of that specific site with some customized endpoint.

If you don't have control over that domain's program, and if they don't provide any API for you, then no.

### Cross Domain Endpoint for Cookie Check

If your "specific site" (secondary domain), you'd need a server program equivalent to this:

```php
<?php

// Allow cross domain access.
// (you may also specify domain by changing "*" to the allowed domain)
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode([
  'fgvisitor_exists' => isset($_COOKIE['fgvisitor']),
]);
```

Which would, if the cookie `fgvisitor` exists for that domain, return this:

```
{
  "fgvisitor_exists": true
}
```

### Using AJAX to Check the Cross Domain Endpoint

Let's say the endpoint in the last step is `https://my-single-sign-on-domain.com/api/fgvisitorExists`, then you may fetch that with javascript on your primary domain:

```
// for modern browsers only, no internet explorer :-)
fetch('https://my-single-sign-on-domain.com/api/fgvisitorExists')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(responseJSON) {
    if (responseJSON.fgvisitor_exists === true) {
      // set cookie, or other operations that you want
      document.cookie = "fgvisitor_exists=true; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2020 12:00:00 UTC";
      // ...
    }
  });
```

When the cookie is set, you may check on the server:

```php
if (isset($_COOKIE['fgvisitor_exists']) && $_COOKIE['fgvisitor_exists'] === 'true') {
  echo 'fgvisitor exists';
} else {
  echo 'no fgvisitor';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I believe they allow for that... They are a directory site, if a user see my site link but doesn't click and decides to manually type my site, or search. The directory loses the referral... So they added a cookie track, so when the user access my site I see they have seen my link over the other site... I'm not sure that's the case

Comment: There are more than 1 way to do cross domain cookie track. But in essence, cross-domain cookie tracking is bad for privacy of visitors. Browsers would want to make sure that both domains allow for that to happen.

Comment: I understand that, but the cookies on the image screenshot, is stored on my browser when I access my own site, there's a tracking pixel in place from the directory site...

Comment: Your browser sees everything. But your server doesn't. Every cookie comes with a domain with it. What your screenshot doesn't show is the domain that the cookie belongs (it is highlighted in blue but is cut off). If the domain is your primary domain, then you should be able to get it in your `$_COOKIE` array. If not, then you'd need to deal with the cross-domain access issue.

Comment: Does your directory site provide any documentation about cookie tracking? They'd probably teach you how to access their tracking cookie there.

Comment: They have provided an iframe code to embed on my site, that's where the cookie shows on my browser when I access my sites cookies... I will check with them on that... thanks